# uninstall mysql in linux server giving error

Tags: linux, mysql, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall mysql 4.1 package in linux server.

Command : `yum remove mysql mysql-server`

It is giving error :

```
    Setting up Remove Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Populating transaction set with selected packages. Please wait.
---> Package mysql.i386 0:4.1.22-2.el4 set to be erased
---> Package mysql-server.i386 0:4.1.22-2.el4 set to be erased
--> Running transaction check
Setting up repositories
http://vault.centos.org/4.8/os/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, '\xe5\x90\x8d\xe5\x89\x8d\xe8\xa7\xa3\xe6\xb1\xba\xe6\x99\x82\xe3\x81\xae\xe4\xb8\x80\xe6\x99\x82\xe7\x9a\x84\xe3\x81\xaa\xe5\xa4\xb1\xe6\x95\x97')>
Trying other mirror.
Cannot open/read repomd.xml file for repository: update
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from update: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from update: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I also tried `yum clean all`

How we can remove mysql?

**Edited:** So which package i need to remove first?

when I run `rpm -e mysql mysql-server` It is throwing:

```
 Failed dependencies:
    libmysqlclient.so.14 is needed by (installed) mod_auth_mysql-2.6.1-2.2.i386
    libmysqlclient.so.14 is needed by (installed) php-mysql-4.3.9-3.26.i386
    libmysqlclient.so.14 is needed by (installed) dovecot-0.99.11-9.EL4.i386
    libmysqlclient.so.14 is needed by (installed) perl-DBD-MySQL-2.9004-3.1.centos4.i386
    libmysqlclient.so.14(libmysqlclient_14) is needed by (installed) php-mysql-4.3.9-3.26.i386
    libmysqlclient.so.14(libmysqlclient_14) is needed by (installed) dovecot-0.99.11-9.EL4.i386
    libmysqlclient_r.so.14 is needed by (installed) MySQL-python-1.2.1_p2-1.el4.1.i386
    libmysqlclient_r.so.14(libmysqlclient_14) is needed by (installed) MySQL-python-1.2.1_p2-1.el4.1.i386
    mysql is needed by (installed) MySQL-python-1.2.1_p2-1.el4.1.i386
    mysql = 4.1.22-2.el4 is needed by (installed) mysql-devel-4.1.22-2.el4.i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Short route: use `rpm -e <pkglist>` instead of `yum remove`. It will accomplish the same thing, though you may have to keep reissuing the `rpm -e` command with an expanded package list because it doesn't automatically depsolve and remove dependent packages for you.

Long route: figure out why the `vault.centos.org` repo isn't responding. Either remove it from your configuration or fix the file for it in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and reissue the `yum remove` command.

Comment: So which package i need to remove first?

Comment: I don't understand why uninstalling an already installed package would require network connectivity in the first place.

Comment: It didn't - the depsolving `yum` was trying to do did. That's why `rpm -e` worked and `yum remove` didn't.